# Problems with certain resolutions with long DVI cables

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dvi, cable

I'm trying to setup my dual-monitor home computer to work with 2x 10 meter DVI cables, but having some trouble seemingly because the cables are too long.

The cables are identical, 10m single-link DVI-D. The monitors are BenQ G2400W. There seems to be no change in behavior when I switch the cables and monitors around - the only difference is what DVI port the monitor is connected to.

The primary DVI port on the graphics adapter works with the 10m cable - the only problem is that the monitor doesn't wake automatically after going to power save/standby (I have to turn it off then back on).

The secondary DVI port works perfectly on resolutions less than 1920x1200, but when I switch to 1920x1200, the monitor is completely black.

I have tried with another 10m DVI cable, but with that I get the typical DVI artifacts on all resolutions  (like https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Teu.jpg). 1920x1200 also shows with this cable, though with lots of the blue artifacts.

With a 5m DVI cable, I have no problems at all (on either monitor/DVI port), so it's obvious the length is relevant here.

That said - I need to have two 10m DVI cables.

Is this likely to be two bad cables? Or perhaps I might buy another graphics adapter? Any suggestions are welcome.

My system:

```
Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
Intel Core2 Quad Q9300 @ 2.50GHz
Nvidia GeForce GTX 580
```

Comment: The purchase of another graphics adapter is unlikely to change anything.  How high quality are these cables?  I personally have very long cables, largest I was able to locate, and I don't have a problem.

Comment: @Nils You said it worked with the 5m cable. Is that cable also single-link DVI? Or is it a dual-link DVI? If it is dual-link then that my be your problem. Here it says that single-link DVI only supports up to 1920x1080: http://www.uwp.edu/departments/campus.technology/information/classroom.technology/forms/documents/DVITypes.pdf

Comment: @PeterMaxwell, both the 10m cable from the primary output as well as the 5m are single-link DVI cables. I have not read about an absolute max resolution of 1920x1080 (it depends also on cable length and frequency, apparently), but 1920x1200 does seem around the upper boundary of what will work. I have bought a 10m dual-link cable now, will test tonight! Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if it works and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, new research in place: I have bought a new, high-quality, 10m dual-link DVI cable. It works exactly the same as the 10m single-link cable - the monitor connected to the secondary DVI output says "Out of range" when I output 1920x1200. The 10m cables (both single- and dual-link) work fine on the monitor from the primary DVI output. The common denominator here is the secondary DVI output. Next step; I'll try inserting another graphics adapter (in addition to the existing one) to see whether the 10m cables work.

Answer (score 0):

DVI-DL cables will support higher resolutions only up to 4.5 meters. For longer lengths you will need a booster, such as Gefen's DVI DL Booster PLUS.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and thanks for helping with this question.  Is there anything you can cite for further reading about this limit?  Also, is that booster just a random example, or a specific recommendation?